# Is it possible not to encode characters on the link/page_path on Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIU9g.png)

On **page path and screen class** dimension, is there a way to not encoded some characters?
On Debug and on realtime result it was not encoded but when I checked it on the report the **#** was encoded to **%23** .

It should be */about/howto#faq* instead of */about/howto%23faq* .

Please help and Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question does not apear to be programming related. you may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ クジェー were you able to get the answer?

Comment: No, It seems it is default on GA4 in its default report. So created custom dimension for it and it is not encoded.